# preview is not working for actions-on-google, web & device

Tags: simulator, preview, actions-on-google

Having trouble getting my action to work in preview.

After installing the app on gcloud I ran....

```
./gactions preview -action_package=agent.json -invocation_name="my action"
```

... and I got...

> Pushing action 'my action' for testing...
>   'my action' is now available for you until 2017-04-08 9:32AM CDT (29 minutes from now)
>   Try 'gactions simulate', then 'talk to my action', or use the Web Simulator at https://g.co/actionswebsim.

Then I ran...

```
./gactions simulate
```

.. and I got...

> User TTS (CTRL-C to stop):

Than from the device I got...

> Sorry I don't know how to help with that...

And from the web simulator I got....

```
{
    "response": "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation",
    "audioResponse": "//NExAASq..."content_copy,
    "debugInfo": {
        "sharedDebugInfo": [
            {
                "name": "GOOGLE_SYSTEM_ACTION",
                "debugInfo": "Your query is handled by Google’s system actions"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 0):

In order for the simulator to invoke your intent, you have to begin with "talk to `your invocation name`" or "at `your invocation name` for `deep link phrase`"

More details here: 
https://developers.google.com/actions/distribute/invocation-and-discovery

Comment: Yes, I tried all the suggested activation words, but no luck.  I'm wondering if the actions SDK is still supported.  Previews work fine via API.AI.

Comment: As it states in the error that your query is using a system action. What response do you get after saying your invocation word?

Comment: Sorry, this action is not available in simulation

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
Just type excatly the following 'talk to my test app'